# Python Pandas time series data divide data on the basis of time

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with GSM data(mcc,mnc,cid,lac) recorded from a smartphone in every 30 seconds. But there will be some data where gap could be anything. Now I have to take every five minutes of data and calculate some features like unique cell ids. I can start with the first row and add five minutes to it. Then find the next row less than or equal to the new time. Also I can create a time delta column. But that too is not very efficient.
Is there any efficinet way to do this in pandas to divide the data based on datetime index.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
                            mcc  mnc      cid   lac  signalis
networktime                                               
2015-10-12 22:04:06.362  405    5    10473  5071        15
2015-10-12 22:04:35.751  405    5    10473  5071        15
2015-10-12 22:05:07.358  405    5    10473  5071        15
2015-10-12 22:05:16.858  405    5    10473  5071        15
2015-10-12 22:06:07.854  405    5    10473  5071        15
2015-10-12 22:06:27.731  405    5    10473  5071        15
2015-10-12 22:07:08.261  405    5    10473  5071        15
2015-10-12 22:07:26.334  405    5    10473  5071        15
2015-10-12 22:08:08.180  405    5    10473  5071        15
2015-10-12 22:08:19.750  405    5    10473  5071        15
2015-10-12 22:08:48.098  405    5    10473  5071        15
2015-10-12 22:09:23.835  405    5  2896027  5822         8
2015-10-12 22:09:53.092  405    5    10473  5071        18
2015-10-12 22:10:19.423  405    5    10473  5071        16
2015-10-12 22:11:08.363  405    5    10473  5071        21
2015-10-12 22:11:19.475  405    5    10473  5071        21
2015-10-12 22:11:48.253  405    5    10473  5071        21
2015-10-12 22:12:19.110  405    5    10473  5071        17
2015-10-12 22:12:48.538  405    5    10473  5071        14
2015-10-12 22:13:22.486  405    5    10473  5071        15
2015-10-12 22:13:48.280  405    5    10473  5071        18
2015-10-12 22:14:48.355  405    5    10473  5071        18
2015-10-12 22:15:21.784  405    5    10473  5071        18
2015-10-12 22:15:54.823  405    5    10473  5071        17
2015-10-12 22:16:22.445  405    5  2894627  5822        11
2015-10-12 22:17:02.702  405    5  2894627  5822        11
2015-10-12 22:17:27.461  405    5  2894627  5822        11
2015-10-12 22:18:08.394  405    5  2894627  5822        11
2015-10-12 22:18:36.883  405    5  2894627  5822        11
2015-10-12 22:18:56.815  405    5  2894627  5822        11
...                      ...  ...      ...   ...       ...
2015-10-15 16:35:22.367  405  800    28492   473        16
2015-10-15 16:35:47.007  405  800    28492   473        16
2015-10-15 16:36:25.389  405  800    28492   473        16
2015-10-15 16:37:09.750  405  800    28492   473        16
2015-10-15 16:37:20.512  405  800    28492   473        16
2015-10-15 16:53:07.070  405  800    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 16:53:36.551  405  800    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 16:53:54.766  405  800    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 16:54:30.815  405  800    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:10:17.531  405  800    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:11:05.349  405  800    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:11:23.439  405  800    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:11:47.869  405  800    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:12:18.418  405  800    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:27:54.367  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:28:32.354  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:28:49.613  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:29:19.621  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:30:02.116  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:30:20.235  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:31:02.206  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:31:34.817  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:32:08.350  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:32:33.349  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:33:19.490  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:34:01.384  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:34:35.664  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:34:49.618  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:35:24.392  405    5    51551   445        12
2015-10-15 17:35:49.674  405    5    51551   445        12
```

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Can you try `df.resample('5min')` this will resample your df to 5min blocks, by default it should preserve the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your data, but the easiest way would be to fix the gap problem of your data first. You can, for example, use [interpolation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) to get equally spaced datapoints out off your timeseries. After this it should be easy to divide the data in 5 min chunks using the .split() method.